# How do I implement logic below using python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[image: output]

I have been asked this question in an interview but I couldn't answer. This question is hunting me since then.

Comment: This is a binary tree question and should be asked on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). It is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a binary tree question. Seems to be asking for a straightforward nested for-loop to print the numbers pyramid above.

Comment: @tiao can you please tell me how do I do that?

Comment: @4M01 What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are obviously slicker ways of doing this with fewer lines of code, but here's one conceptually simple solution (in Python 3):

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in range(n-1):
...     print(' ' * (n-i-2), end='')
...     for j in range(i+1):
...             print((n-i)*(j+1), end='')
...             print(' ', end='')
...     print('')
   5
  4 8
 3 6 9
2 4 6 8
```